# How to read Sala-i-Martin datasets?

Tags: r, data

I found the datasets used in Barro and Sala-i-Martin's papers from the early 1990s. I have no idea how these could be read to either Stata or R.

The file formats are .h, .wf , .wk1 and .wk4.

I believe .h and .wf files work together (for example one of the .h file just contains variables)

I think, .wk1 and .wk4 have something to do with Lotus spreadsheet (which I do not have).

Question: Does anyone know how to read these to R?
I do not mind opening them in a safe freeware first to convert them to some common format.

This is Sala-i-Martin's data website: [http://www.columbia.edu/~xs23/data.htm](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Exs23/data.htm)
I am talking about the first three data - US, Japan and Europe.

Note: I am not sure if this is very suitable for Econ SE, but since this is Econ data from some very well-known research, I thought someone might have faced this issue before. Please let me know if I should migrate this.

Comment: At least .wk1 files can be converted to various spreadsheet formats using https://onlineconvertfree.com/file-format/wk1/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGreinecker. I am going to try that. Though, I am still not sure how to read the other files.

Comment: I think TSP files refer to the TSP econometrics sofware [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSP_(econometrics_software)). Probably wf files can be read by Eviews (if you have a copy).

Comment: @tdm Thanks for the information.